# Swift - regex vs components/join: which is more efficient for String operations

Tags: swift, regex, string

I need to remove excessive spaces between words in Swift (there won't be more than 5 words in a given string), not sure which is more efficient: regular expression or normal components and join?

For example:

```
Hello   world! My name is     Tom.
```

Result:

```
Hello world! My name is Tom.
```

Method 1:

```
let result = input.components(separatedBy: " ").filter { string -> Bool in
    return string.isEmpty == false
}.joined(separator: " ")
```

Method 2:

```
let result = input.replacingOccurrences(of: "[ \t]+", with: " ", options: .regularExpression, range: range)
```

Comment: The performance is irrelevant unless you are having an issue. Are you doing this in a loop on thousands of strings or are you doing this once on a single string?

Comment: @rmaddy about 3 strings at one time, so I guess there's no obvious difference?

Comment: You can run some performances tests (do not use the playground for this) if you really want to know but avoid premature optimizations. Use the code you prefer and find easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Try it out! In a sample project (not Playground) keep the current date as start date, create a loop and perform the operation 100000 times. Then get the elapsed time. Compare both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run some performance test, feeding the entire script of Romeo and Juliet line by line to both functions (see [online sample](http://rextester.com/JMMG62430)).

I was actually a bit surprised that the regex replace is almost on par with the components/string operation: the regex is just ~2x slower:

```
|     Approach      | abs. running time | cpu time | Time to evaluate func | memory peak |
|-------------------|-------------------|----------|-----------------------|-------------|
| components/string | 0.21 sec          | 0.2 sec  | 0.11 sec              | 9 Mb        |
| regex replace     | 0.33 sec          | 0.36 sec | 0.21 sec              | 34 Mb       |
```

This does not mean much. Probably the only noticeable difference is the peak memory consumption. But even if you run the regex replace in a reasonable number of parallel loops it should be fine. Nonetheless, always run your own test with your real code.

The bottom line, however, is as commented by [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy)

> Use the code you prefer and find easier to read and maintain.